# Deleting specific text files

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os 
folder = 'C:/Python27/Data'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

This is the code I use for deleting text files from directories, but I would like to delete specific files, filtering them based on some keywords.
If a text file doesn't contain the word "dollar", than delete it from the folder. This should be done for all the files inside the directory.

Comment: Just to make sure: You mean that the *file* contains the word, not the *filename*? Also, it seems your code would delete a lot more than just text files...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes if it `not` contain the `word` , word may b like this `dollar056` or `dollar12112ab` etc , if it have no word like this , than it should delete that text files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are rather small, then the following simple solution would be adequate:

```
if os.path.isfile(file_path): # or some other condition
    delete = True             # Standard action: delete
    try:
        with open(file_path) as infile:
            if "dollar" in infile.read(): # don't delete if "dollar" is found
                delete = False 
    except IOError:
        print("Could not access file {}".format(file_path))
    if delete: 
        os.unlink(file_path)
```

If the files are very large and you don't want to load them entirely into memory (especially if you expect that search text to occur early in the file), replace the above `with` block with the following:

```
        with open(file_path) as infile:
            for line in file:
                if "dollar" in line:
                    delete = False
                    break
```

Comment: You could improve this solution by filtering files not by using `os.path.isfile()`, but e.g. using a set of known extensions like `.txt`, `.md` etc..

Comment: @whatyouhide: Certainly (that's why I commented on the question). Perhaps the directory in question only contains text files...